# Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) - unable to instantiate receiver - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

As soon as the app starts or when the push notification is sent from the server, the following traceback happens.

```
08-31 02:00:14.733: E/AndroidRuntime(30973): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.example.smsmining.GcmBroadcastReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.smsmining.GcmBroadcastReceiver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.smsmining-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.smsmining-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
08-31 02:00:14.733: E/AndroidRuntime(30973):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2405)
08-31 02:00:14.733: E/AndroidRuntime(30973):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-31 02:00:14.733: E/AndroidRuntime(30973):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1332)
08-31 02:00:14.733: E/AndroidRuntime(30973):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-31 02:00:14.733: E/AndroidRuntime(30973):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-31 02:00:14.733: E/AndroidRuntime(30973):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
08-31 02:00:14.733: E/AndroidRuntime(30973):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-31 02:00:14.733: E/AndroidRuntime(30973):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-31 02:00:14.733: E/AndroidRuntime(30973):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
08-31 02:00:14.733: E/AndroidRuntime(30973):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-31 02:00:14.733: E/AndroidRuntime(30973):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-31 02:00:14.733: E/AndroidRuntime(30973): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.smsmining.GcmBroadcastReceiver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.smsmining-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.smsmining-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
08-31 02:00:14.733: E/AndroidRuntime(30973):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
08-31 02:00:14.733: E/AndroidRuntime(30973):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
08-31 02:00:14.733: E/AndroidRuntime(30973):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
08-31 02:00:14.733: E/AndroidRuntime(30973):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2400)
08-31 02:00:14.733: E/AndroidRuntime(30973):    ... 10 more
```

My Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.smsmining"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />


     <permission android:name="com.example.smsmining.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.smsmining.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

         <receiver android:name="com.example.smsmining.SMSBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>



         <receiver
            android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.example.smsmining" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

GcmBroadcastReceiver.java

```
package com.example.smsmining;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver;


/**
 * This {@code WakefulBroadcastReceiver} takes care of creating and managing a
 * partial wake lock for your app. It passes off the work of processing the GCM
 * message to an {@code IntentService}, while ensuring that the device does not
 * go back to sleep in the transition. The {@code IntentService} calls
 * {@code GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent()} when it is ready to
 * release the wake lock.
 */

public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                GcmIntentService.class.getName());
        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

GcmIntentService.java

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

    public GcmIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
    }
    public static final String TAG = "GCM Demo";

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
        // in your BroadcastReceiver.
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        if (!extras.isEmpty()) {  // has effect of unparcelling Bundle
            /*
             * Filter messages based on message type. Since it is likely that GCM will be
             * extended in the future with new message types, just ignore any message types you're
             * not interested in, or that you don't recognize.
             */
            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " + extras.toString());
            // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
                // This loop represents the service doing some work.
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Working... " + (i + 1)
                            + "/5 @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
                Log.i(TAG, "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                // Post notification of received message.
                sendNotification("Received: " + extras.toString());
                Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
            }
        }
        // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }

    // Put the message into a notification and post it.
    // This is just one simple example of what you might choose to do with
    // a GCM message.
    private void sendNotification(String msg) {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle("GCM Notification")
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
        .bigText(msg))
        .setContentText(msg);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Comment: Try replace `<receiver
            android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"` with `<receiver
            android:name="com.example.smsmining.GcmBroadcastReceiver"`

Comment: I tried it already. It didn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've got the same errors. This helped me.
Try to check the v.4 library.
**Properties->Java Build Path->Order and Export**

Edited:
Select project and go to: Properties->Java Build Path->Order and Export, make sure android.support.v4 library is checked in the list, if not, mark it. (i assume you already imported the library to project), clean project and it should work

Comment: Select project and go to: Properties->Java Build Path->Order and Export, make sure android.support.v4 library is checked in the list, if not, mark it. (i assume you already imported the library to project), clean project and it should work

Comment: In other words, make sure the Android Support library is being included in the build.

Answer (score 2):

change

```
.GcmBroadcastReceiver
```

to

```
com.example.smsmining.GcmBroadcastReceiver
```

and

```
.GCMIntentService
```

to

```
 com.example.smsmining.GCMIntentService
```

After that, clean project.
That works for me.